# Rendering the price correctly in react store app

Tags: reactjs, cart, price

After i adding my products to the cart i need to change value of the specific product and i want to automaticlly change the price, but after try to change the value, price is changing in every product in the cart and pass the price to other products from the changing product.

How can i solve this issue ?

```
function CartItems ( {cart, handleRemove} ) {
     
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(false);

  const handleValue = (e, id) => {
    let selectedValue = e.target.value;
    let currentPrice = cart.map((item) => item.id === id ? selectedValue * item.price : item.price) 
    setPrice(currentPrice);
    console.log(currentPrice)
  }

  return (
    <div  className='cart_item'>
      {cart.map((item, id) => (
        <div key={id} className='cart_item--item'>
           <div className="cart_item--image">
                <img
                  className="cart_item_image--img"
                  src={item.image}
                  alt="/"
                ></img>
              </div>
              <div className='cart_item--content'>
              <h3 className="cart_item--h3">{item.title}</h3>
              <select className='cart_item--value' onChange={(e) => handleValue(e,item.id)}>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
              </select>
              <p className="cart_item--price">{`Price: ${price ? price : item.price}`}
                <span>{<BiEuro />}</span></p>
                <button onClick={() => handleRemove(item)}>Remove</button>
              </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default CartItems
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
<p className="cart_item--price">{`Price: ${price ? price : item.price}`}
```

You're causing the price of each item to display as the price of the currently selected item, so you should remove that ternary:

```
<p className="cart_item--price">{`Price: ${price}`}
```

And if you wanted to display a price based on the quantity of items selected, you need to use an object in your state that maps from an item ID to a price like so:

```
const [priceMap, setPriceMap] = useState({})

  const handleValue = (e, id) => {
    let selectedValue = e.target.value;
    let currentPrice = cart.map((item) => item.id === id ? selectedValue * item.price : item.price) 
    setPriceMap({...priceMap, [item.id]: currentPrice});
  }
```

And then render it in your code like follows:

```
<p className="cart_item--price">{`Price: ${priceMap[item.id] === undefined ? item.price : priceMap[item.id]}`}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the "current" price for each item could be different, so you need more than a single variable to account for different prices for different items (hence the suggested use of an object as a "price map")

Comment: This solution do not  work ; / ,  but thank you for your help :)